# How can my project access its "resources" directory both when run in Eclipse and from a Maven-packaged jar file?

Tags: eclipse, maven, resources, m2e

I'm working with Maven project in Eclipse (with help of m2e plugin). When I pack my project into jar-file (mvn install), all files from "resources" are located in the root of jar.

Therefore, in my program I should use only bare file names:

```
File file = new File("foo.txt");
```

But when I build and run my project by Eclipse, I would have to use the relative path to the file:

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/foo.txt");
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You may find the answer in the following similar question's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359876/how-to-load-reference-a-file-as-a-file-instance-from-the-classpath/4360001#4360001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your program's resources, don't use `File`, `FileInputStream` and similar classes.
They will not work for anything inside a jar file.

Instead, use `Foo.class.getResource(...)` or `.getResourceAsStream()` to access your resources. (Read the documentation before doing so.)

I'm not sure if a program started from eclipse can access these - please try and report back!

Comment: Yes, a program started either from Eclipse or from a JAR file can access these as long as they are placed on CLASSPATH, i.e. in the `src/main/resources` directory.

Comment: Yes, it's working in Eclipse. But one detail: m2e plugin exclude src/main/resources from classpath (this problem is described [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273009/maven-and-eclipse-problem-looking-for-resources)). So you should erase one line from .classpath file and everything will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your package configuration in Eclipse is wrong, cause it sees src/main/resources as a package instead of a source folder.

The configuration in Eclipse must look like this: [image]

Comment: when I include src/main/resources into classpath - it didn't help