# For a Maven project to access its own resources

Tags: maven, resources, dependencies

I have two projects:
A project 
B project (lists A as one of B's dependencies)

A has a method that relies on A's resource

When B calls A's method, A ends up access B's resource folder and thus is unable to find A's own resource files.

Any way around this?

Comment: You should load the resources via this.getResourcesAsStream("/name-of-a.properties");...

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095539/how-can-my-project-access-its-resources-directory-both-when-run-in-eclipse-and

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that a project will always access its own resources, you need to load them using the [Class#getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) method.

Example:

```
public class MyCalledClass{
    public static void loadResource() {
        new File(MyCalledClass.class.getResource("file.txt").getPath()); // Will retrieve the file called "file.txt"
                                                                         // in the project where this class is

        new File("file.txt");  // Will retrieve the file called "file.txt" in the project calling this method
    }
}
```