# Accessing resource file incorrectly

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to access a resource file in eclipse using the following snippet.

```
public class ResourceHandler {

    public void test() throws IOException {
        String filePath = this.getClass().getResource("resources/MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF").getPath();// throws a NPE
        System.out.println( filePath );
        //System.out.println( file.exists() );
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        ResourceHandler test = new ResourceHandler();
       test.test();
    }
}
```

Here's a pic of my directory structure.
[image: Directory structure]

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.getClass().getResource` will try and look for the resource relative to the current class (`com/spring/helloWord`), try using  `/resources/MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF` instead

Comment: So by your theory shouldnt `String filePath = this.getClass().getResource("/src/main/resources/MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF").getPath();` work? It throws a NPE as well

Comment: No, so `/resources/MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF` should work, `src/main` won't exist once the project is built properly...

Comment: I guess so, using `resources/MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF` will do a relative search based on the package of the class used to call `getResources`, using `/..` cause the search to start from the root of the classpath...

Comment: Actually my bad. The approach isnt working. Here's a code snippet as to what I'm doing based on your suggestion. It still throws a file not found exception. `String filePath="/resources/MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF";
  URL url= new File(filePath).toURI().toURL();
  
   if(url!=null)
   {
   
    InputStream  is= url.openStream();
    
   
   }`. Is this exactly what you meant?

Comment: No, I meant: `this.getClass().getResource("/resources/MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF")`, don't try and treat these resources as a `File`, in most cases the resource will be embedded within the Jar file and won't act like a `File`, that's the point of having the `URL`...

Comment: Sure. But that actually throws a NPE. As in the following code.`public void test() throws IOException {
  URL url=this.getClass().getResource("/resources/MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF");
  
 
    InputStream  is= url.openStream();
    }
`. Sorry for the protracted discussion.

Comment: They you need to ensure that the resource is actually getting added to your project's classpath/build.

Comment: Weird. I thought `src/main/resources` was on the build path by default. Eclipse thinks so too and isnt allowing me to add the folder again.

Comment: Clean/build/export the project and check the resulting Jar file...

Comment: Done. Here's the screenshot of the unzipped jar file https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwredobi7my4vwe/Screenshot%202014-10-22%2020.55.24.png?dl=0. What do you think? It has both the ResourcerHandler.class and resources/MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF . I'm totally confused.

Comment: Certainly looks like it exist.  Have you tried running the Jar file manually?

Comment: You mean the program manually?

Comment: From the command line, using `java -jar helloword-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: It works. What's happening in eclipse then?

Comment: Well at least we know it's an issue with Eclipse.  Check that the resources directory is part of the projects classpath

Comment: It doesnt let me add the resources directory. Citing that its already there( as before). https://www.dropbox.com/s/ufga4vqes99jw8m/Screenshot%202014-10-22%2021.03.58.png?dl=0

Comment: That's the build path, what about the class path...not a use of eclipse but I understood they were different...

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273009/maven-and-eclipse-problem-looking-for-resources)

Comment: Weird. I thought both were effectively the same till today. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, so I'm only going by what I've been told and heard :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach is to use the getResource from the Classloader. So it will work in any place, including a web container.

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF");
if (resource != null) {
    String path = resource.getPath(); // You can try getFile...
}
```

Comment: change "MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF" to ".". It should show the folder the classloader is point to.

Comment: It points to `helloworld/target/classes/` where helloworld is the name of the project.

Comment: I fix a typo on my answer. Did you copy the code from here? MANIFEST_HAPPYVERSION.MF was wrong. Can you try again?

Comment: And check the helloworld/target/classes for the MANIFEST file... Is there one?

Comment: Nope. Im trying to access it from `resources/`

Comment: It should be something with your project configuration. The MANIFEST file should be there. I do that all the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63534/discussion-between-kodeseeker-and-diogosantana).

Comment: @KodeSeeker Did you get it done? What was the problem?

Comment: Build path was messed up . Thanks. More so the classpath in eclipse .